# How to include a separate git repository and modify it as part of a project?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a project and it depends on a separate project I have made. It would be convenient to include it as a git submodule or similar, but I need to make a small commit to the dependency in order for the projects to work together. I can't add the commit to the git repo of the dependecy since it's only relevant for this other project.
Is there a way to store a local commit to a submodule repo within the root repo? Is there something other than a submodule that could be used?

I tried making a commit in the submodule without pushing it but that just creates a commit that cannot be found when fetching from another computer.

Comment: @Kombajnzbożowy Yes that seems to answer my question. Through the question you linked I can also find multiple other similar questions pointing in the same direction [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38944165/push-git-submodule-changes-to-my-own-repo), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745014/push-submodule-changes-in-git), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16951165/how-to-push-commits-from-changes-made-to-a-submodule-into-main-git-repo)]. I guess there is no way to do exactly what I wanted but at least I have some more throughts on alternative approaches.